Hahn Banach Extension Theorem from Brezis Functional Analysis
I'm going through the proof for the Hahn-Banach Extension Theorem from Brezis' functional analysis book. Here is proof:

$$P = \Big\{ h: D(h) \subset E \to \mathbb{R} \big| D(h) \text{is linear subspace of }E, h \text{is linear}, G \subset D(h), h \text{ extends } g, h(x) \le p(x) \forall x \in D(h) \Big\}$$ On $P$ we define the order relation $$(h_1 \le h_2) \Leftrightarrow (D(h_1) \subset D(h_2) \text{ and } h_2 \text{ extends } h_1$$ Let $Q \subset P$ be a totally ordered subset; $Q= (h_i)_{i \in I}$, and set $$D(h) = \bigcup_{i \in I} D(h_i), h(x) = h_i(x) \quad \text{if } x \in D(h_i) \text{ for some } i.$$ Then $h \in P$ and $h$ is an upper bound for $Q$. Using zorn's lemma, there exists a maximal element $f$ in $Q$. We want to show that $D(f) = E$. Suppose not, i.e., $D(f) \neq E$. Let $x_0 \in D(f)$; set $D(h) = D(f) + \mathbb{R}x_0$ and for every $x \in D(f)$, set $h(x + tx_0) = f(x) + t\alpha$. We must ensure that $$f(x) + t \alpha \le p(x + tx_0) \quad \forall x \in D(f) \text{ and } \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$... it suffices to check that $$\begin{cases} f(x) + \alpha \le p(x + x_0) \\ f(x) - \alpha \le p(x-x_0)\end{cases}$$ In other words, we must find some $\alpha$ satisfying $$\sup_{y \in D(f)} f(y) - p(y - x_0) \le \alpha \le \inf_{x \in D(f)} p(x + x_0) - f(x).$$ Such an $\alpha$ exists since $$f(y) - p(y-x_0) \le p(x+x_0) -f(x) \quad \forall x \in  D(f), \forall y \in D(y)$$ indeed, from the subadditivity, $$f(x) + f(y) \le p(x+y) \le p(x+x_0) + p(y-x_0).$$ Then $f \le h$ which is impossible since $f$ is maximal and $h \neq f$.

The part I do not get is the last inequality. I get the subadditivty part but how do we get $f(x) + f(y) \le p(x+y)$?

$f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)\le p(x+y)$.

@Jochen I am so dumb. Thank you.
